# Compute instant throughput

Tags: throughput

I have to write a program that must print the instant throughput for a network interface. I can see every single packet that is transiting over that interface and, if I wanted, deeply inspect that packet.
I just want to show the instant throughput but I don't know how to do it.
I thought to add into a counter variable the dimension of the packet and to show it every second before clearing but I think it is too much an euristic approach.
How can I do to get a real instant thoughput?

Comment: What language are you using ? Do you have some code ?

Comment: True instant throughput would be either wire speed if there's a packet coming in or going out, or 0 if not, and it would vary on a microsecond to microsecond basis.  If that isn't what you want, you might want to figure out the period of time over which you want to average the throughput.